# Run Kafka Consumers on Google Cloud Run

Tags: apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a large application with lots of microservices that communicate through Kafka. Right now it's working on GKE.

We are moving Kafka to confluent.io and we were planning to move some of the microservices to Google Cloud Run (fully managed).

BUT,... it looks like Google Cloud Run (fully managed) does not support listening to kafka events, right? Are there any plans to support it? Is there a workaround?

**EDIT:**

This [post](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-eventing-kafka) shared by **andres-s**, shows that you can implement your own cloud run and have it connected to confluent kafka, in Anthos.

It would be great to have this option in the fully-managed Google Cloud Run service.

But in the meantime, the question would be: is it possible to implement it in a regular GKE cluster (not Anthos)?

Comment: AFAIK, Cloud Run fully managed is compliant with Knative serving API, not with eventing. And so, you can't link both world without a wrapper/translator

Comment: Sorry, my bad,... you're right, it's built using Knative serving API. I was confused, I thought it was using Knative eventing API. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: Anthos is marketing in your case!! Anthos means "manage several clusters (GKE, EKS, AKS, on prem,...) in a single place". If you use simply GKE, the sticker Anthos is just marketing!

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud has a fully managed [Kafka solution](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-eventing-kafka) through SaaS partner Confluent, which uses Cloud Run for Anthos (with GKE)

Google Pub/Sub is the GCP alternative for Kafka, but through [Confluent](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-and-confluent-partner-to-deliver-a-managed-apache-kafka-service) you can use kafka on GCP

Comment: I'm planning on moving Kafka from my GKE cluster to Confluent, but it doesn't solve my problem. I wanted to run my microservices using the fully-managed Google Cloud Run service.

Anyways, thanks for sharing the post. Do you know if it will work in a regular GKE cluster (not Anthos)?

Comment: It won't work without anthos directly, maybe the workaround suggested by Jason Jay Smith could help

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Run is just Knative SERVING. It is stateless and spins up when it receives events. Due to this, it can't really subscribe to a topic and pull an event.

Knative Eventing is more stateful in nature and handles the pulls and subsequently triggers the pods running Knative Serving. They, ideally, are used together to give you the full serverless experience.

The good news is, there is a "hack". You can do [Kafka to PubSub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector) then [PubSub to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub). If you are adventurous and don't mind OSS software, there are a number of Knative Eventing tutorials at serverlesseventing.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the proxy part from Kafka to Pub/Sub, and I understand that Pub/Sub can trigger my microservices, by calling an HTTP endpoint they expose. 

But... the problem is that right now my microservices don't expose HTTP endpoints, but they listen to Kafka topics.

To implement your proposed solution, I would need to modify my microservices to expose HTTP endpoints instead of listening to Kafka topics. Am I right? Or should I make them listen to PubSub directly?

Comment: You would need to expose it to HTTP but you don't necessarily have to to expose it to the world or can secure it by requiring authentication. But yes, for now, Cloud Run does require HTTP/S exposure.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification :) ... also, I noticed you are the author of this post https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-run-eventing-kafka ... that's the approach I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Run does support Kafka consumers, but you need to enable the flag “–no-cpu-throttling” on your Cloud Run service (this will increase the costs). Also, you need to create a VPC Connector between the Kafka and the Service and inform the Connector name on the service via “–vpc-connector”

My kafka is in a VM and my services in cloudrun and it works perfectly!